# Which XCode template should I use for this game?

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d

I'm currently building a multiplayer mobile game for iOS using SceneKit. It's going to be a 2-player 3D game with a single view per player over the playing field, with both players facing each other. A good analogy for my game would be "1v1 paper toss, using the accelerometer". I'm a first year CS student, so I'm trying to keep it simple.

I'm aware that this game already exists on the app store, I'm only doing this for a school project. The XCode framework that I originally thought I would use was "game" (obviously..), but after doing some further research, I came across some information that led me to believe that a "single view application" could be used as well, as the game only requires 1 view per player. Does anybody have any input on whether I should stick with game or use the single view application? I struggled to figure out how to create a main menu using only game, and it seemed like this may be the solution. This is my first game I've ever built, so I'm sorry if this is an incredibly noobish question.

Comment: I think you should go with the game (sprite-kit) framework. It's very clean and makes things less complicated for game specific tasks. You can learn a lot about it here http://www.raywenderlich.com/ good luck!

Comment: Even if I'm making the game 3d?

Comment: You can combine spritekit and scenekit for 3D games http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/combining-the-power-of-spritekit-and-scenekit--cms-24049 I think this would work best

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.